# how to make dynamic cards and iterate through arrays in ejs

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js, ejs

I'm new to `node js` and `ejs templating`. I'm trying to build a website. I need to make dynamic profile cards based on the count from database. I'm using `mysql` and `sequelize`. When I use `FindAndCountAll` I have an array

```
{
    count: 3,
    rows: [
        patient_data {
            dataValues: [Object],
            _previousDataValues: [Object],
            _changed: Set(0) {},
            _options: [Object],
            isNewRecord: false
        },
        patient_data {
            dataValues: [Object],
            _previousDataValues: [Object],
            _changed: Set(0) {},
            _options: [Object],
            isNewRecord: false
        },
        patient_data {
            dataValues: [Object],
            _previousDataValues: [Object],
            _changed: Set(0) {},
            _options: [Object],
            isNewRecord: false
        }
    ]
}
```

which I get from `console.log` 'gen' from this api

```
Login: async(req,res,next) => {

    try {
        if(!req.body){
            throw new Error(" sorry no data");
        }

        const { name, password} = req.body;
        console.log("b",name)
        const user= await models.machine.findOne({
            where:{
                name:m_name
            },
        });


        if (user) {
            let isPassWordCorrect =  await bcrypt.compare(password,user.password)
            if(isPassWordCorrect){

                const gen= await models.patient_data.findAndCountAll({
                    attributes:[
                        "p_id","gender","name",
                    ],
                    where:{
                        m_name:machine_name
                    }
                });

                var arr = gen;
                console.log(arr,"ae")

                res.render('dash',{ posts: gen })

                console.log(posts)

            } else {
                res.redirect('/Login')
            }
        } else {
            res.status(400).json({
                message:"unsuccess , an errror occured",
            })
        }

    } catch (err) {
        res.status(400).json({
            message:err.toString(),
        });
    }
}
```

When I use `FindAll` I get this array with data values.

```
[
    patient_data {
        dataValues: { p_id: '054', gender: 'M', name: 'Pau' },
        _previousDataValues: { p_id: '054', gender: 'M', name: 'Pau' },
        _changed: Set(0) {},
        _options: {
            isNewRecord: false,
            _schema: null,
            _schemaDelimiter: '',
            raw: true,
            attributes: [Array]
        },
        isNewRecord: false
    },
    patient_data {
        dataValues: { p_id: '075', gender: 'M', name: 'Dav' },
        _previousDataValues: { p_id: '075', gender: 'M', name: 'Dan' },
        _changed: Set(0) {},
        _options: {
            isNewRecord: false,
            _schema: null,
            _schemaDelimiter: '',
            raw: true,
            attributes: [Array]
        },
        isNewRecord: false
    },
    patient_data {
        dataValues: { p_id: '75', gender: 'M', _name: 'vin R' },
        _previousDataValues: { p_id: '75', gender: 'M', _name: 'vin R' },
        _changed: Set(0) {},
        _options: {
            isNewRecord: false,
            _schema: null,
            _schemaDelimiter: '',
            raw: true,
            attributes: [Array]
        },
        isNewRecord: false
    }
]
```

The problem is I'm unable to create dynamic cards based on the count and show it in my `ejs` page. I'm using `express`, `ejs`, `mysql` and `sequelize`.  I need to render the array which I can, but catching the rendered values and showing it on my `ejs` page is bit confusing. Is there any way to iterate over this array and show the values in each cards. Can somebody help me.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be due to sending model instances to the `ejs` renderer.  Try this query instead:

```
const gen = await models.patient_data.findAndCountAll({
    attributes:[
      "p_id","gender","name",
    ],
    where:{
      m_name:machine_name
    },
    raw: true
  });
```

The [raw option](https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/model.js%7EModel.html#static-method-findAll) will just return the data, which is more suitable for `ejs`.  Then, you could do something like the following in your `ejs` file:

```
<h1>
    Patient Data Test
</h1>
<ul>
    <% locals.posts.rows.forEach(function (patient) { %>
        <li class="patient-data">
            <div>Name: <%= patient.patient_name %></div>
            <div>Gender: <%= patient.gender %></div>
        </li>
    <% }); %>
</ul>
```

And, although I'm not that great at `CSS`, perhaps something like:

```
* {
    font-family: arial, helvetica, verdana, sans-serif;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}

.patient-data {
    box-shadow: 0 0 15px #ccc;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 1rem;
    line-height: 1.5rem;
}

.patient-data:not(:first-child) {
    margin-top: 1.5rem;
}
```

Comment: Hi i get this output                                                                                                                     {
  count: 3,
  rows: [
    { p_id: 'PAU054', gender: 'M', patient_name: 'Paul Pavish' },
    { p_id: 'DAV075', gender: 'M', patient_name: 'Davincy' },
    { p_id: 'MAR075', gender: 'M', patient_name: 'Marvin R' }
  ]
}

Comment: and in my ejs  i use this                                                                                                      <ul>
  <h1>patient data test</h1>
  <% arr.forEach(function(bean) { %>
    <tr> 
        <li><%= bean%></li> 
      
    </tr> 
<% }); %>

</ul>      to show my values. i know since the output is a string forEach can't be used. how to solve this mate.

Comment: @fungusblacky Added `ejs` and `css` snippets.  You can still use `.forEach(...)`.  Hope this helps!